# Error saving a file on server

Tags: c#, xamarin, server, bouncycastle

I am generating a Key and i need to record on server. When i tried locally, it Works ! The problem is when i try on the server...
The archive is generated but when ON THE SERVER the download finish,but i cannot open and cannot save. I don´t get an error...but i just cannot save...

The code:

```
                string fileNamePrivate = @"pasta1/archive.txt";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNamePrivate));
                StreamWriter textWriterPriv = new StreamWriter(fileNamePrivate, true);
                var pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriterPriv);
                pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Private);
                pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
                textWriterPriv.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
string fileNamePrivate = "~/PASTA1/archive.txt";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(fileNamePrivate)));
StreamWriter textWriterPriv = new StreamWriter(fileNamePrivate, false);
```

How is a Server you have to use HostingEnvironment.MapPath and set "false" instead "true" on StreamWriter if you need to overwrite.